# Page break is landing on the wrong line

Tags: excel, vba, page-break

My page break is landing in the wrong row. I need it to go up one line. Instead of the page breaks between rows (3 & 4), (10 & 11), (17 & 18), (24 & 25), I need it to land between (2 & 3), (9 & 10), (16 & 17), 23 & 24). The code finds "Shipment Order" then adds HPageBreak below the cell not above it.

Visual of the problem:

[image]

Code:

```
Sub APageBreakbyOrder()

ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks

Dim SFind As Integer
Dim LR As Integer

    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For SFind = 1 To LR
    If Cells(SFind, 1).Value = "Shipment Order" Then
    ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Rows(SFind + 1)
    End If
    Next

End Sub
```

This code works great, I just need to move the page break line up one for each loop. How can I do this?

Comment: Ehhrm, why don't you simply adjust the calculation in `Before:=Rows(SFind + 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the page break is one row too low, then chances are it will be correct if you remove the `+ 1` in the line

`ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Rows(SFind + 1)`

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: So, I found a bigger issue that was beyond the +1 in my overall code. I set a "Print Area" macro that starts at my first row Shipment Order. So when the "Page Break" code starts it can't start before the first Shipment Order row...because there is no row. So it errors out. Answer: 1. Make sure the first line has an extra row above the first row it's going to pick. 2. Add ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "" to the beginning of the code...Then Page Break Macro...then Print Area Macro.